# Unable to update flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, sdk

I am trying to run commands like `flutter upgrade` and `flutter doctor` and even when I try to check for channel `flutter channel` but it is showing me just these particular set of commands -

```
Downloading Dart SDK from Flutter engine <<<<<<< HEAD
2dce47073a378673f6ca095e91b8065544c3a881
=======
91c9fc8fe011352879e3bb6660966eafc0847233
>>>>>>> d79295af24c3ed621c33713ecda14ad196fd9c31...
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL

Failed to retrieve the Dart SDK from: https://storage.googleapis.com/flutter_infra_release/flutter/<<<<<<< HEAD
2dce47073a378673f6ca095e91b8065544c3a881
=======
91c9fc8fe011352879e3bb6660966eafc0847233
>>>>>>> d79295af24c3ed621c33713ecda14ad196fd9c31/dart-sdk-darwin-x64.zip
If you're located in China, please see this page:
  https://flutter.dev/community/china
```

If anyone has faced a similar problem or has any idea what to do...please help.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have merge conflict markers in your Flutter SDKs internal files (for example `bin/internal/engine.version`).

You may be able to fix this with `flutter ugprade --force` or by following the instructions here:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Workarounds-for-common-issues#flutter-installation-corrupted

Run the following commands **in the Flutter install directory**:

```
git clean -xfd
git stash save --keep-index
git stash drop
git pull
flutter doctor
```

Answer (score 0):

change engine.version CRLF -> LF

for more info you can look at this
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/35921